# target of uri doesn't exist in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have a project typed with dart Flutter, I have created a folder on the main project called 'packages' in the packages I have user_repository.dart file.

When I tried to import this file on the main.dart this error appeared:

`import 'package:user_repository/user_repository.dart'`

I have tried `Flutter clean` & `Flutter run` but nothing change, anyone can help?

Comment: Import should be something like
import 'package:project_name/directory_name/file_name.dart';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a package to work, you need a `pubspec.yaml` file and `lib` directory inside the package folder.

To create a flutter package inside your project, first open your project directory, (or wherever you want to create the package) and run:

```
flutter create --template=package your_package_name
```

If you want to create a `plugin` package that contains `platform-specific` code, you can use the `--template=plugin` flag instead of `--template=package1`. For example:

```
flutter create --template=plugin your_plugin_name.
```

then, update your project `pubspec.yaml` file, like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  your_package_name:
    path: ./your_package_name # or wherever you created the package
```

Use `flutter pub get` to add the package to your list of available packages. Now you can use

```
import 'package:your_package_name/some_file.dart';
```

For more info, look at [developing packages](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages).